# Unable to import module 'handler': Error for serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

Error: `Unable to import module 'handler': Error for serverless`

Here is my handler:

```
`use strict`
const fetch = require('fetch')

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Hello, world!')
  callback(null)
}
```

Here is my serverless.yml:

```
service: salsifyapicronjob
provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-central-1
  runtime: nodejs6.10
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
    - schedule:
        rate: cron(*/5 * * * ? *)
        enabled: true
```

I did notice inside the .serverless zip that the handler.js is not in there. Could this be the reason? And if so how do I fix that?

Comment: Where is your `handler.js` file in relation to the `serverless.yml` file?

Comment: Same directory as the serverless. I tried doing `./handler/hello` and no luck

Comment: Did you remember to run `npm install`?